# phonegap file uploading in server not working

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, xcode, cordova

i am using phonegap audio recording.

All the functionality working perfectly except the file upload on the server.

```
function uploadFile() {
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                var recordingPath = $('#audiopath').val();
                var name = $('#audioname').val();
                alert('Path is: ' + recordingPath);
                ft.upload(recordingPath,
                          "http://lab1.XXXXXXX.com/XXXXXX/upload.php",
                          function(result) {
                          alert(result);
                          console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                          console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
                          },
                          function(error) {
                          console.log('Error uploading file ' + recordingPath + ': ' + error.code);
                          },
                          { fileName: name });   
            }
```

and my php file code is,

```
$new_image_name = time()."audio.wav";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["recordingPath"]["tmp_name"], "/XXXXX/www/XXX/XXX/filefromphone/".$new_image_name);
```

Previously i am saving file full path and file name into two hidden fields and getting the value in button click.

The file is no't uploading man. It's chewing my whole day. where i am wrong.

Comment: do you get any errors? Do you http logs show the server being hit? Need more details.

Comment: no, this is what i getting ..................2012-08-24 19:07:05.839 Varsity[22975:707] File Transfer Finished with response code 200
2012-08-24 19:07:05.871 Varsity[22975:707] [INFO] Upload success: 200
2012-08-24 19:07:05.873 Varsity[22975:707] [INFO] 605815 bytes sent

Comment: This is what i am getting in upload.php  ...                                                                         $filesize = sizeof($_FILES); ==== 1  ......                                                                                  $_FILES["file"]["name"] == blank

Comment: In our success method log what "result.response" is so you can see what the response from the web server is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=$('#audioname').val();
options.mimeType="audio/wav";
options.chunkedMode = false;
```

I add this code on the top of the function before initialize `new FileTransfer();`

and it's working now....
Hope it will help others too

Comment: I've been having the same problem, spent about two hours to fix it. Now the wav on the server has file size: 0. The wav won't open at all. The player says I need a codec. Anyway I'm pretty sure something went wrong with the upload cause the sound plays on the device. Did you by any chance have had the same problem?(I hope you did lol)

Comment: The phonegap file transfer plugin sends the wav with size 0.